# ¿Cómo declarar una matriz cuadrada en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

tengo un programa que me está dando `undefined` debido a que definí mal mi arreglo multidimensional.

en Java lo haría así:

```
int[][] array=new int[][] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
final int filas = array.length;
final int columnas = array[0].length;
int[][] returnedArray = new int[columnas][filas];
```

pero en javascript no sé como hacerlo.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
var array=[[1, 2], [3, 4]];
var returnedArray = [[columnas],[filas]];
var returnedArray = [[columnas,filas]];
var returnedArray = [];
```

pero cualquier intento de llenar los índices del `returnedArray` me está fallando.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: espero te sirva :https://tutorias.co/category/lenguajes-de-programacion/programacion-en-javascript/

Comment: gracias @Tegito123 pero me resulta demasiado confuso ese sitio :s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suponiendo que quieres crear una matriz 2*2, lo puedes hacer asi:

```
var matrix = [];
for(var i=0; i<columnas; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new Array(filas);
}
```

para el caso en particular lo más cercano sería

```
var returnedArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<columnas; i++) {
 returnedArray[i] = new Array(filas);
}
```

Comment: no quiero una matriz de 2x2 quiero una de mxn

Comment: Puedes cambiar el numero 2 por cualquier variable.

Comment: listo, por favor modifica tu código a 
`var returnedArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<columnas; i++) {
      returnedArray[i] = new Array(filas);
    }
`
para poder aceptar la respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes lograr de la siguiente manera;

```js
    var arreglo = [
      ['posicion1', 'posicion2']
    ];
    console.log(arreglo [0][0]);
```

Puedes tambien crear un objeto;

```js
    
    var myObj = { 
    fred: { apples: 2, oranges: 4, bananas: 7, melons: 0 }, 
    mary: { apples: 0, oranges: 10, bananas: 0, melons: 0 }, 
    sarah: { apples: 0, oranges: 0, bananas: 0, melons: 5 } 
}
console.log(myObj.fred);
```

Comment: El ancho y alto de la matriz deberían ser iguales, ya que es cuadrada.

Comment: eso es inicialización, yo solamente la quiero declarar

Answer (score -2):

Asi creas una Matriz de 4x4 con numeros random por ejemplo. podes adaptarla a tu nececidad.

```js
var matrix = [
  []
];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

    matrix[[i, j]] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;

  }
}

console.log(matrix)
```

Comment: curioso que la tratar de correr tu código da matrices vacías

Comment: No se puede indizar así.  Tiene que ser `[i][j]` y también te falta agregar un arreglo por cada *fila*: `matrix[i] = []`.

Comment: Hola Lucio, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, tu respuesta es errónea, te sugiero que la elimines o la edites para evitar recibir votos negativos.